# Submitting formatted JSON with PHP form

Tags: php, json, forms

## Files

### index.php

```
<form name="postform" action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="postarea" id="postarea">
    <tbody>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">Date:</td><td><input type="text" name="startDate"></td></tr>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="headline"></td></tr>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">Article:</td><td><textarea id="text" rows="5" cols="30" type="text" name="text"></textarea> </td> </tr>
<tr>    <td class="assetblock">Image address:</td><td><input type="text" name="media"></td></tr>
<tr>    <td class="assetblock">Image caption:</td><td><input type="text" name="caption"></td></tr>

<tr>    <td class="postblock"></td><td> <input type="submit" value="Submit Entry"> </td>    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</form>
```

### post.php

```
<?php
// check if a form was submitted
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){
// convert form data to json format
$json = json_encode( $_POST );
// make sure there were no problems
//if( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
    //exit;  // do your error handling here instead of exiting
// }
$file = 'entries.json';
// write to file
//   note: _server_ path, NOT "web address (url)"!
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

## Question

I am trying to create a form that will allow my users to add entries to the site. Entries are stored in a JSON file. I have created a form that submits to the JSON form and is formatted like this:

```
{"startDate":"example",
"headline":"example",
"text":"example",
"media":"example",
"caption":"example"}
```

Media and caption relate to an image, video or other multimedia, i need them to be stored as a separate object like the example below.

```
 {"startDate":"example",
 "headline":"example",
 "text":"example",
 "asset" :{"media":"example",
          "caption":"example"}
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
// check if a form was submitted
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){

// convert form data to json format
    $postArray = array(
      "startDate" => $_POST['startDate'],
      "headline" => $_POST['headline'],
      "text" => $_POST['text'],
      "asset" => array(
         "media" => $_POST["media"],
         "caption" => $_POST['caption']
        )
    ); //you might need to process any other post fields you have..

$json = json_encode( $postArray );
// make sure there were no problems
//if( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
    //exit;  // do your error handling here instead of exiting
// }
$file = 'entries.json';
// write to file
//   note: _server_ path, NOT "web address (url)"!
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You know [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)? Simply pass an assisiative array to this function with the given structure

Create an new array i.e and pass it to json_encode

```php
$array = array(
    "startDate" => $_POST['startDate'],
    //..
    "assets" => array(
            "media" => $_POST["media"]
            //..
    )
);
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: as far as i know $_POST is an associative array. so whats your point??

Comment: $_POST is an associative array, but not in the format you want. As Philipp stated, move the assets to its own array with subkeys and then convert the entire array via Json. 

Bonus comment: Remember that if you want to use json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE you need PHP 5.3 or higher.